# Hiding the the information in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

Is there a way to hide your profile in math.stackexchange, by this I mean to not allow public to see your profile including the questions that you asked and answered without deleting them.

Comment: ok if my question is stupid please just tell me and I will remove it.

Comment: If you wonder why the downvotes, maybe the downvoters think doing something like that would not be useful. Perhaps it would help why you think such a feature could be useful. (It is clear that someone who wants to cheat by posting all homework or take-home-exam questions on this site would consider something like that useful. I hope it is your case. I can imagine some legitimate reasons: For example asking about something sensitive, such as something concerning your adviser and similar stuff. But in such cases, you could probably post as an unregistered user instead using your account.)

Comment: (Personally, I did not downvote, what I wrote in the above comment is just my guess.) And perhaps, since this is your first post on meta (or at least your profile page shows only this question), I should also mention that meaning of upvotes and downvotes [is different on meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Related question on meta.SE: [Optional anonymity to hide ignorance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/optional-anonymity-to-hide-ignorance)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you very much for your explanation, yes indeed this is my first time.

Comment: @MartinSleziak One thing that might be worth pointing out (indeed, I am only discovering this now), is that the MetaFAQ states that voting indicates (dis)agreement on meta posts tagged "feature-request", which this one is not. I think that a lot of users vote this way on all meta questions, although if this is true, I'm not sure if it makes most sense to change the FAQ or users' behaviour - I can make a pretty good guess which would be easiest though! Of course, the FAQ isn't literally wrong, but might be misleading.

Comment: @MattPressland: I would say that maybe, just maybe, the (discussion) tag can also fall into that. But certainly not (support) or (bug) as a blanket statement, since posts in those two tags often do not have any element of personal opinion. In fact I think it would be better if users try to avoid downvoting a new user asking what could be a honest support question. (Note that here he did not ask anything like: "if it is not possible, can we make this a feature?")